# Create button....move to second screen containing image and use zoom funcationality

Tags: android

I would like to have a button to navigate to second screen containing Image and then use the zoom operation on the image present in second screen.
I could do the zoom funcationality in one screen screen when I run into second screen using Intent and Startactivity, zoom functionality is not working. Please help me.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code machine.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you start a new `Activity` with button click i.e. by using an `Intent`, you will have to set zoom functionality again on that `ImageView` in your second `Activity`.

See this, it is an excellent source to learn [how to set zoom functionality](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-6-implementing-the-pinch-zoom-gesture/1847) .